# Add Elements of Data Frame to Another Data Frame Based on Condition R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have two data frames that showcase results of an analysis from one month and then the subsequent month.

Here is a smaller version of the data:

```
Jan19=data.frame(Group=c(589,630,523,581,689),Count=c(191,84,77,73,57))
Dec18=data.frame(Group=c(589,630,523,478,602),Count=c(100,90,50,6,0))

Jan19
  Group Count
1   589   191
2   630    84
3   523    77
4   581    73
5   689    57

Dec18
  Group Count
1   589   100
2   630    90
3   523    50
4   478     6
5   602     0
```

Jan19 only has counts >0. Dec18 is the dataset with results from the previous month. Dec18 has counts >=0 for each group. I have been referencing the full Dec18 dataset for counts =0 and manually entering them in to the full Jan18 dataset. I want to rid myself of the manual part of this exercise and just be able to append the groups with counts = 0 to the end of the Jan19 dataset.

That lead me to the following code to perform what I described above:

```
GData=rbind(Jan19,Dec18)
GData=GData[!duplicated(GData$Group),]
```

While this code resulted in the correction dimensions, it does not choose the correct duplicate to remove. Among the appended dataset, it treats the Jan19  results>0 as the duplicate and removes that.  This is the result:

```
Gdata
   Group Count
1    589   191
2    630    84
3    523    77
4    581    73
5    689    57
9    478     6
10   602     0
```

Essentially, I wanted that 6 to show up as a 0.  So, that lead me to the following line of code where I wanted to set a condition, if the new appended data (Dec18) has a duplicate Group to the newer data (Jan19), then that corresponding Count should=0.  Otherwise, the value of count from the Jan19 dataset should hold.

```
Gdata=ifelse(Dec18$Group %in% Jan19$Group==FALSE, Gdata$Count==0,Jan19$Count)
```

This is resulting in errors and I'm not sure how to modify it to achieve my desired result.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm having trouble tracking your goal. Is this right: You want to create a new data frame named `Gdata` that has all the `Group` data in either `Jan19` or `Dec18`, and the `Count` data that is `Jan19` if it is there, and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rbind`/deduplication approach is a good one, you just need the `Dec18` data you `rbind` on to have have the `Count` column as 0:

```
Gdata = rbind(Jan19, transform(Dec18, Count = 0))
Gdata[!duplicated(Gdata$Group), ]
#    Group Count
# 1    589   191
# 2    630    84
# 3    523    77
# 4    581    73
# 5    689    57
# 9    478     0
# 10   602     0
```

> While this code resulted in the correction dimensions, it does not choose the correct duplicate to remove. Among the appended dataset, it treats the `Jan19` results>0 as the duplicate and removes that. This is the result:

This is incorrect. `!duplicated()` will keep the first occurrence and remove later occurrences. None of the `Jan19` data is removed---we can see that the first 5 rows of `Gdata` are exactly the 5 rows of `Jan19`. The only issue was that the non-duplicated rows from `Dec18` were not all 0 counts. We fix this with the `transform()`.

---

There are plenty of other ways to do this, with a join using the `merge` function, we could only `rbind` on the non-duplicated groups as d.b suggests, `rbind(Jan19, transform(Dec18, Count = 0)[!Dec18$Group %in% Jan19$Group,])`, and there are others too. We could make your `ifelse` approach work like this:

```
Gdata = rbind(Jan19, Dec18)
Gdata$Count = ifelse(!Dec18$Group %in% Jan19$Group, 0, Gdata$Count)

# an alternative to ifelse, a little cleaner
Gdata = rbind(Jan19, Dec18)
Gdata$Count[!Gdata$Group %in% Jan19$Group] = 0
```

Use whatever makes the most sense to you.